# Wiener-Hopf factorization of matrices

Tags: cv.complex-variables, matrices, matrix-analysis

Given a $2\times2$ matrix, which entries are functions in the complex plane $$\hat{A}(z)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a(z)&b(z)\\c(z)&d(z)\end{array}\right)$$Where $a(z),b(z),c(z)$ and $d(z)$ are functions in the complex plane. I would like to obtain two new matrices, denoted as $\hat{\phi}_+(z)$ and $\hat{\phi}_-(z)$, such $\hat{A}(z)=\hat{\phi}_+(z)\hat{\phi}_-(z)$. The meaning of the subindexes is related to the discrete Fourier transform. If we take $\hat{\phi}_+(z)$
$$\int dz e^{i k z}\hat{\phi}_+(z)=0,\;\;\forall\;k<0$$
Similar definitions can be given for $\hat{\phi}_-(z)$ with $k>0$. It means that the Fourier transform of the two functions is only non-zero in a half complex plane.

As far as I know, this is called Wiener-Hopf factorization. 
My questions are about the conditions that ensure the  existence of such a factorization, and how this factorization can be determined (references or examples may help at this point).

Thank you for any help!

**Note**: Suppose that the entries of $A(z)$ are continium and smooth, and the matrix is invertible a.e. ($\mbox{det}[\hat{A}(z)]\neq0,\forall z\in \mathbb{C}$) By the moment I don't care about pathological cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers to the literature on matrix-Wiener-Hopf factorization can be found in [A brief historical perspective of the Wiener-Hopf technique:](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.426.46&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

> Matrix Wiener-Hopf kernels are fundamentally distinct from their
>   scalar counterparts in that there is no algorithmic approach to
>   determining the factorisation of the transformed kernel. Exact
>   factorisation can be achieved for matrices with certain special
>   features: those that are upper (or lower) triangular in form; those
>   that are of Khrapkov-Daniele, i.e. commutative, form; those whose
>   elements comprise meromorphic functions; kernels with special
>   singularity structure that allows the Wiener-Hopf equation to be
>   recast into uncoupled Riemann-Hilbert problems and $N \times N$
>   matrices with special algebraic or group structure.

More specifically, for the $2\times 2$ case, see for example [Matrix Wiener-Hopf factorization](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.426.9671&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (and this related [note):](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.426.5656&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

> A method is described for effecting the explicit Wiener-Hopf
>   factorisation of a class of $2\times 2$ matrices. The class is
>   determined such that the factorisation problem can be reduced to a
>   matrix Hilbert problem which involves an upper or lower triangular
>   matrix. Then the matrix Hilbert problem can be further reduced to
>   three scalar Hilbert problems on a half-line, which are solvable in
>   the standard manner.

This explicit method works if 
$$b\left[a-d\pm\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4bc}\right]^{-1}$$
can be expressed as a ratio of polynomials in $z$. It seems a completely general explicit construction does not exist, not even for $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: Thank you Carlo! I didn't know about the existence of the last work, which seems quite general for the $2\times2$ case, and solves the problem at least in this case.